# Gnome3 - set screen energy settings from command line (script)

Tags: debian, gnome3, gsettings, screen-energy-saving

Is there a way to access, set gnome system-settings from the command-line?

I'm specifically interested in a way to set:

```
settings -> energy -> screen off = never
settings -> energy -> screen off = (N) minue(s)
```

I would like to access this settings from a bash script, so I could set screen-off to `never` when the script starts and back to `(N) minue(s)` before the script exits.

I hope my question is clear, since I just translated the menu hierarchy from a German-GUI.

I tried to find a setting with `gsettings` but could not really get my way through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I found it, this is pretty nice since it's set in `seconds` you can also set a value shorter then a minute:

```
# Set "turn screen off" to (N)seconds:
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay N

# Set "turn screen off" to never:
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

# Set "turn screen off" to 1 minute (60)seconds:
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 60
```

---

In the script I use it as follows:

```
# getting the time of current setting and store to variable 'screenoff'
  screenoff=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay \
               | awk '{print $2}')

# set "turn screen off" to never
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

  echo "lots of important information being printed..."

# set back to the former setting:
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay "$screenoff"
```

the value stored into `$screenoff` would of course get lost if the script was canceled before completion.

---

**A workaround** could be to store the value to a `temporary file`, which gets `removed` at the very end of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check if there is a temporary file from an aborted session
# read from this file or get value from gsettings & write temporay file:

  if [ -f "./.screenoff.tmp" ]; then
      screenoff=$(cat "./.screenoff.tmp")
  else
      screenoff=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay \
                   | awk '{print $2}')
      echo "$screenoff" > "./.screenoff.tmp"
  fi

# switch power saving off:
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay 0

  echo "lots of important information being printed..."

# Set "turn screen off" back to original value:
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay "$screenoff"

# remove temporary file
  rm "./.screenoff.tmp"
```